# Aggreating/removing string in row with list while preserving other values (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a unique GRID ID and the names of several protected areas. I needed to keep the fact that some PAs were overlapping inside of a several grid cell and have got that far by using groupby. However I have several names repeated and would like to get rid of these duplicated values to just have the unique values left.

My df looks like this:

```
GRID ID | Name
AB-66   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AB-67   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AC-56   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AC-57   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AC-58   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AC-59   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna di Venezia: Valle Averto', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AC-65   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
AC-66   | ['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']
```

So as you can see for example Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia is repeated often in a row - how do I remove instances of duplication and just keep 1 of the repeated name?

Comment: Is it important to keep the order of the sentences?

Comment: `lst = list(set(['Laguna di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia', 'Laguna medio-inferiore di Venezia']))` use set and remove duplicates

Comment: No the order of the sentences isn't important @mozway

Comment: @balderman I have about 13,000 rows of different names is there anyway to do this without specifying exactly?

Comment: It is just an example...Pass the data to set and wrap it with list --> duplicate is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is not important, convert to set (and eventually again to list):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

if you don't necessarily need a `list` as container:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(set)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work but why do I lose my GRID ID value (even when I reset index)?

Comment: This should not affect other columns. Can you edit your question and provide the content of your dataframe as dictionary (`df.to_dict()`)?